# Open attribute edit when feature is selected using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins

For my plugin I want the user to be able to select a feature and an edit window popup for editing a certain attribute of that feature. I could do this by making a QInputDialog.getText show up when a feature is clicked. But I'm wondering if there is a more straight forward way to bring up an attribute edit box using pyqgis. Here is the class I am using as the selection tool:

```
class NumberTool(QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature):

    def __init__(self, plugin, iface, layer):
        self.plugin = plugin
        self.iface = iface
        self.canvas = self.iface.mapCanvas()
        self.layer = layer
        self.selected = []
        QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature.__init__(self, self.canvas, self.layer)
            
    def canvasPressEvent(self, event):
        found_features = self.identify(event.x(), event.y(), [self.layer], QgsMapToolIdentify.TopDownAll)
        if found_features:
            # open attribute edit box. how do this?
            self.layer.triggerRepaint()
            self.plugin.add_label_layer()
            self.plugin.move_layers()

    def deactivate(self):
        self.layer.removeSelection()
```

Comment: One of the ways is to add custom action of python type to your layer. Have you considered it?

Comment: @RainForest I'm not sure what that means or what that would look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with a Qt popup, like this;

```
class NumberTool(QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature):

def __init__(self, plugin, iface, layer):
    self.plugin = plugin
    self.iface = iface
    self.canvas = self.iface.mapCanvas()
    self.layer = layer
    self.selected = []
    QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature.__init__(self, self.canvas, self.layer)
        
def canvasPressEvent(self, event):
    found_features = self.identify(event.x(), event.y(), [self.layer], QgsMapToolIdentify.TopDownAll)
    if found_features:
        feature = [feature.mFeature['line_id'] for feature in found_features]
        label, ok = QInputDialog.getInt(self.plugin, 'Line Label', 'Enter Label:')
        if ok:  
            query = "UPDATE planning.line \
                    SET line_label = %s \
                    WHERE line.line_id = %s", (label, feature[0],)
            self.plugin.db_conn.query(query, fetch=False)
            self.plugin.final_lines.triggerRepaint()
            self.plugin.add_label_layer()
            self.plugin.move_layers()

def deactivate(self):
    self.layer.removeSelection()
```

But if anyone knows of a way to change the attribute directly (which would update the database) please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I mean something like this in my comment:

Create your own attribute edit form and select it in layer properties. Add your logic in python code.

[image]

Create new action for the layer.

[image]

New action "edit" is available in list of actions

[image]

Comment: Ok interesting, I'll look into that, thank you. Actually I'm pretty happy with the popup method I'm using so I'll probably stick with that, but this is good info.